# Delay function doesn't work on .removeClass()

Tags: jquery

I'm making my own slider using Jquery, There're 2 buttons to navigate through the sliders (next button) and (previous button)

I made on('click') event on the next button to make my operations on the slider

first of all i got the active slider animated it to go to left by -3500px then i want to remove the active class from it but when i use removeclass the class is removed without the animation

```
$('.header .next-slider').on('click', function() {

$('.header .sliders .slider.active').animate({
                left:-3500
            },1000).delay(4000).removeClass('active').next().css({
                right:-3500
            }).addClass('active').animate({
                right:0
            },1000);
});
```

The slider disappear before showing animation.. it should show animation then disappear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's delay function only works with animations.  However, you could use a setTimeout once the animation is complete.

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {
    $('#thing').animate({
        left: -3500px
    }, 1000, function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#thing').removeClass('active');
        }, 3000);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot <3
i forgot about the callback function

Comment: @MiDo Please mark the question as answered if this solved your issue.  Thanks!